# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. Error with Tkinter and Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Beginner Question: I have built my first few scripts that create a database table from a .csv file. I have added a little GUI on them, as the tutorials have shown me, but I am having a lot of trouble trying to write a simple function that will add a new data record to my database table when I press the Add Entry button that calls the "Insert" function. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? I would be very appreciative. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3 
import csv

###Create a database###
conn = sqlite3.connect("Cereals.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cereals")
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "Cereals" (
"Cereal_ID" INTEGER Primary Key,
"Cereal_Name" STRING,
"MFR" CATEGORICAL,
"Type" CATEGORICAL,
"Calories" INTEGER,
"Protein" INTEGER,
"Fat" INTEGER,
"Sodium" INTEGER,
"Fiber" FLOAT,
"Carbo" FLOAT,
"Sugars" INTEGER,
"Potass" INTEGER,
"Vitamins" INTEGER,
"Weight" REAL,
"Cups" FLOAT,
"Rating" FLOAT
)
''')

###Import data from a CSV File###
fname = "Cereal.csv"

with open(fname) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=';')
    next (csv_reader)
    next (csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
        Cereal_Name = row[0]
        MFR = row[1]
        Type = row[2]
        Calories = row[3]
        Protein = row[4]
        Fat = row[5]
        Sodium = row[6]
        Fiber = row[7]
        Carbo = row[8]
        Sugars = row[9]
        Potass = row[10]
        Vitamins = row[11]
        Weight = row[12]
        Cups = row[13]
        Rating = row[14]
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Cereals(Cereal_Name,MFR,Type,Calories,Protein,Fat,Sodium,Fiber,Carbo,Sugars,Potass,Vitamins,Weight,Cups,Rating)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(Cereal_Name,MFR,Type,Calories,Protein,Fat,Sodium,Fiber,Carbo,Sugars,Potass,Vitamins,Weight,Cups,Rating))
conn.commit()

###Import data from a CSV File###

def insert():
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Cereals (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",(Cereal_Name.get(),MFR.get(),Type.get(),Calories.get(),Protein.get(),Fat.get(),Sodium.get(),Fiber.get(),
                   Carbo.get(),Sugars.get(),Potass.get(),Vitamins.get(),Weight.get(),Cups.get(),Rating.get()))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


window = Tk()


l1=Label(window,text="Cereal")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
l2=Label(window,text="MFR")
l2.grid(row=1,column=0)
l3=Label(window,text="Type")
l3.grid(row=2,column=0)
l4=Label(window,text="Calories")
l4.grid(row=3,column=0)
l5=Label(window,text="Protein")
l5.grid(row=4,column=0)
l6=Label(window,text="Fat")
l6.grid(row=5,column=0)
l7=Label(window,text="Sodium")
l7.grid(row=6,column=0)
l8=Label(window,text="Fiber")
l8.grid(row=7,column=0)
l9=Label(window,text="Carbohydrates")
l9.grid(row=8,column=0)
l10=Label(window,text="Sugars")
l10.grid(row=9,column=0)
l11=Label(window,text="Potassium")
l11.grid(row=10,column=0)
l12=Label(window,text="Vitamins")
l12.grid(row=11,column=0)
l13=Label(window,text="Weight")
l13.grid(row=12,column=0)
l14=Label(window,text="Cups")
l14.grid(row=13,column=0)
l15=Label(window,text="Rating")
l15.grid(row=14,column=0)

Cereal_text = StringVar()
e1=Entry(window,textvariable =Cereal_text)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

MFR_text = StringVar()
e2=Entry(window,textvariable =MFR_text)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)

Type_text = StringVar()
e3=Entry(window,textvariable =Type_text)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1)

Calories_text = StringVar()
e4=Entry(window,textvariable =Calories_text)
e4.grid(row=3,column=1)

Protein_text = StringVar()
e5=Entry(window,textvariable =Protein_text)
e5.grid(row=4,column=1)

Fat_text = StringVar()
e6=Entry(window,textvariable =Fat_text)
e6.grid(row=5,column=1)

Sodium_text = StringVar()
e7=Entry(window,textvariable =Sodium_text)
e7.grid(row=6,column=1)

Fiber_text = StringVar()
e8=Entry(window,textvariable =Fiber_text)
e8.grid(row=7,column=1)

Carbo_text = StringVar()
e9=Entry(window,textvariable =Carbo_text)
e9.grid(row=8,column=1)

Sugars_text = StringVar()
e10=Entry(window,textvariable =Sugars_text)
e10.grid(row=9,column=1)

Potassium_text = StringVar()
e11=Entry(window,textvariable =Potassium_text)
e11.grid(row=10,column=1)

Vitamins_text = StringVar()
e12=Entry(window,textvariable =Vitamins_text)
e12.grid(row=11,column=1)

Weight_text = StringVar()
e13=Entry(window,textvariable =Weight_text)
e13.grid(row=12,column=1)

Cups_text = StringVar()
e14=Entry(window,textvariable =Cups_text)
e14.grid(row=13,column=1)

Rating_text = StringVar()
e15=Entry(window,textvariable =Rating_text)
e15.grid(row=14,column=1)

b1 = Button(window,text = "Add entry", width=12,command=insert)
b1.grid(row = 16, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Inside `insert()` function you want to use StringVar objects e.g. `Cereal_text`, not `Cereal_Name` which is `str` object - field name from the header. Same for all the rest.